# How do i add columns to datatable from rows from another datatable

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I have a DataTable called `dt` which is filled with values from excel.

> On line 6 (row) i have my header information

**Code i have now**

```
   string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C:\Users\thoje\Desktop\stack\forslag.xlsx;" +
        @"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;""";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string sql = @"SELECT * from [Ark1$]";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(rdr);



                }
            }
        }
        DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();



        //foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        //{

        for (int i = 5; i <= dt.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {


            if (i == 6)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
                dt2.Rows.Add(dr);

            }


            else if(i >=8)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
                dt2.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
```

**What i need is:**

> 1. I want all my data on row 6 to become headers in a new DataTable
> 2. All data after line 7 i need to append to this new Datatable with the new headers.

**What my code shows:**

My code now shows how to do it on a DataTable which is cloned, so therefore i have the wrong headernames.

Comment: Please post complete code witha  minimum veririfiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate through all rows if you only need 1 of them.

```
DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
DataTable dtTarget = new DataTable();

// Get row at index == 6 (7th line as this is a 0-based-index)
var headerRow = dtSource.Rows[6];

// Iterate through all values
foreach(var value in headerRow.ItemArray)
{
    // For each value create a column
    // and add it to your new dataTable
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(value.ToString());
    dc.Caption = value.ToString();
    dtTarget.Columns.Add(dc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - This was  just what i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

using a linq approach might be good:
a pseudo way:

```
 //linq query to select row 
 var query = from myRow in
 myDataTable.AsEnumerable() where myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 6 
 select myRow;

// Create a table from the query DataTable newTable =
query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: Thanks im not that skilled in linq, but thanks for the effort

Comment: @plaidDK Thank you for positive comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty confusing to read, and keeps talking about rows where I'd expect columns etc, but I'll make the following assumptions:

- You have an excel file with 5 blank rows and then a row of headers, and then data rows
- You've successfully imported this data into a Datatable called dt
- You want to end up with a datatable that has the values in row 6 as the column names, and the blank rows removed

Code:

```
for(int i = 5; i >= 0; i--){
  if(i == 5)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
      dt.Columns[j].ColumnName = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
  }
  dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

You don't need to clone the datatable. Watch out for strings that make for poor column names (containing chars like '[' ) making your life miserable further down the line ..

Comment: Code works fine; I've fixed a couple of typos, nothing the compiler didn't warn about, but there's nothing wrong with the logic..